# What are these rusted metal objects found on a beach?

Tags: beach, manmade-object-identification, faroe-islands

On a very secluded beach on the Faroe Islands (half a day's hike from the nearest road, and you have to climb down a 50m cliff using an old rope), I found these rusted metal objects. They're about 80cm long (daisies for scale) and lay near a lot of driftwood and old buoys.

My first suspicion would be a naval mine, but I'm far from sure.

[image: Metal Object]

Comment: Naval mines was my first thought too, but it seems odd that they'd be on land like that. Though nearby driftwood and old buoys would lend some more credibility to that theory.

Comment: that's a lobster, obviously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like decommissioned harbor mines. At the end of World War II many were removed from river mouths & harbors. Once set out you can not use them again, so they removed the explosive & primer, then dumped the rest close to the place where it had been decommissioned. They were deactivated, then thrown on the beach.

This one is too rusty to tell for sure.

Comment: Certainly looks similar to images of naval mines on google.